# Bash Find Gateway

Tags: arrays, bash, join, split

I'm not a bash expert at all.  I'm trying to find my gateway by manipulating my found public IP and modifying the last byte:

205.207.123.138 -> 205.207.123.1

set to variable
split variable on "."
replace last entry with 1
array join

Any advice appreciated.  Cheers

Comment: This sounds interesting. How did you go? Also; How did you set the *"variable split"* variable?

Comment: I honestly have no memory of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's no guarantee that the gateway will be at that address, I think this would do what you're suggesting:

```
IP="205.207.123.138"
GW=${IP%.*}.1
```

Comment: Hey thank you.  Super simple.  Ya those are my instructions, so I have to run with it.  I guess this is more of an array question than networking.  Cheers